# How to optimize a recursive function that traverses a voxel trying to find all cells of a specific property?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am working on a voxel (volume element) issue and here's my descriptions:

1. I have a voxet which you can understand as a Nx by Ny by Nz cube;
2. for each cell of this voxel, it has a region ID so that we could tell the regions of the cube; the following picture shows a voxet:
   [image]
3. My target is to separate the cells by its region ID, and put the cells that has the same region ID into a list called SeparateRegion

Thus, I wrote the function SeparateRegion(int ID) as follows:

```
public bool SeparateRegion(int ID)
{

    RegionCellIndex = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
    Visited = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, bool>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.nU; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.nV; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < this.nW; k++)
            {
                if (this.voxelCenterNodes[i, j, k].RegionID == ID)
                {
                    Tuple<int, int, int> tuple = new Tuple<int, int, int>(i, j, k);
                    RegionCellIndex.Add(tuple);
                    Visited.Add(tuple, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (RegionCellIndex.Count <= 0) return false;

    int blobCount = 0;

    SeparateRegionsList = new List<List<Tuple<int, int, int>>>();

    for (int index = 0; index < RegionCellIndex.Count; index++)
    {
        Tuple<int, int, int> tuple = RegionCellIndex[index];
        if (!Visited[tuple])
        {
            List<Tuple<int, int, int>> SeparateRegion = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();

            SeparateRegion.Add(tuple);
            CountHelper(tuple, SeparateRegion);
            SeparateRegionsList.Add(SeparateRegion);
            blobCount++;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Number of Blocks: " + blobCount);
    return true;
}
```

And in the above function, I used a recursive function: CountHelper(Tuple<int, int, int> tuple, List<Tuple<int, int, int>> SeparateRegion) to generate SeparateRegion:

```
private void CountHelper(Tuple<int, int, int> tuple, List<Tuple<int, int, int>> SeparateRegion)
{
    if (!Visited.ContainsKey(tuple))
        Visited.Add(tuple, false);
    Visited[tuple] = true;
    Voxet.Node node = this.voxelCenterNodes[tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3];
    SeparateRegion.Add(tuple);
    foreach (Node neighbor in node.NeighbourVertices)
    {
        Tuple<int, int, int> neighborTuple = new Tuple<int, int, int>(neighbor.I, neighbor.J, neighbor.K);
        if (neighbor.RegionID == node.RegionID)
        {
            if (!Visited.ContainsKey(tuple) || !Visited[neighborTuple])
            {
                CountHelper(neighborTuple, SeparateRegion);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the variable Visited is a Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, bool> to track the cell that already visited.

this function runs ok when my cell number is relatively small (for example, 30x30x100), **however, when the number increases(30x30x200), the recursive funtion CountHelper reports "StackOverflow" problem.**

I think this issue **probably** comes from the recursion becomes too big. However I could not find a way to optimize it. I appreciate if anyone could solve this issue.

Comment: Voxel, not voxet.

Comment: Does the CountHelper implement a seed filling ?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0097849310000725

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am not familiar with seed-filling but I can explain the idea of CountHelper:  basically it sets the parameter tuple (a cell) as visited and the traverse all its neighbor cells that has the same region ID and do the recursion. I think that is somehow similar to seed-filling

Comment: Yep, this is seed filling. The required stack depth can be as large as the number of voxels in a region, and that can be huge. Two cures: using an explicit stack or using more sophisticated algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the stack overflow problem is to use a separate stack instead of recursion. Pseudo code would typically look something like:

```
var visited = new HashSet<NodeIndex>();
var stack = new Stack<NodeIndex>();
while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    var current = stack.Pop();
    if(visited.Contains(current)) continue;
    foreach (var neigbors in GetNeightbors(current))
    {
        stack.Push(neigbors);
    }
}
```

To get decent performance you will really want to avoid any allocations inside the loop. This means getting rid of `Tuple<>`, since that creates an object. You also want to ensure it has en efficient `GetHash` implementation, and while `ValueTuple<>` is a value type and therefore gets Equals for free, *I think* it always returns zero for hash. So I would suggest using a custom struct for the node index. If you can live with a maximum size for the volume you might also consider using `short` or `byte` for the indices, to reduce memory usage and fit more of the data in the cache.

Comment: Hi @JonasH,  I used you pseudo code and it works almost fine, but I just found that the results is unstable: that is, each time I run the code, the connected regions has slightly different number of cells. However, I do not see any problems in the pseudo code, which confused me a lot.

Comment: For example In my first round, the biggest connected region has 34493 cells, while in the second round, it has 34550 cells.

Comment: @Lake_Lagunita There is nothing in the iteration code that is unstable. If you get different values it is because the input is different, or you have some other unstable code somewhere. Possible places it the code that generates or evaluates neighbors, or incorrect equality comparison for the node index.